# Pre-post test with control group

Tags: anova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs)

I'm doing an action research study with 2 of my classes: 1 is the 'treatment' class and the other is the 'control'.

Both classes undertook a pre-test prior to the 'treatment'.

Then, after the 'treatment' stage (the control class didn't receive any 'treatment'), both classes did a post-test.

What statistics should I use? Paired t-tests? ANOVA with repeated measure? Help!

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3466/930)?

Answer (score 0):

Covariance analysis.
The post-test is your dependent variable.
Class 1 versus class 0 is the independent variable. 
The pretest is the covariate.